# Trim a string by the index of the first letter character

Tags: python

I have a list of categories:

```
categories = [
    '01-1 Category 1',
    '01-2 Category with a lot of spaces between words',
    '01   Only one code category',
    '02 1 Two codes category'
]
```

The task is to cut off the category code  and keep only category names. So the output should be:

```
# pprint.pprint(output_list)

['Category 1',
 'Category with a lot of spaces between words',
 'Only one code category',
 'Two codes category']
```

I solved it:

```
for category in categories:
    letter_index = 0

    for char in category:  # find index of first letter
        if char.isalpha():
            break

        letter_index += 1

    output.append(category[letter_index:])
```

It seems the solution looks like C-style. Is there more pythonic way to solve the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a list comprehension to do the loop and the `lstrip()` method of strings to strip off numeric characters, hyphens, and spaces.

```
categories[:] = [category.lstrip("0123456789- ") for category in categories]
```

Comment: what does the syntax `categories[:] = ...` mean? The result looks the same if I write only `categories = ...`.

Comment: It's a slice assignment. It replaces the contents of the existing list, whereas the other syntax creates a new list.

Answer (score 1):

I wrote following code, which is equivalent to your original but more concise.

```
categories = [
    '01-1 Category 1',
    '01-2 Category with a lot of spaces between words',
    '01   Only one code category',
    '02 1 Two codes category'
]
def trim(x):
    return ''.join(x[[i.isalpha() for i in x].index(True):])
output = [trim(i) for i in categories]
print(output)
```

Output:

```
['Category 1', 'Category with a lot of spaces between words', 'Only one code category', 'Two codes category']
```

Explanation: I used so-called `list` comprehensions. Inside function `trim` I am creating list of boolean values, then I am getting index of first `True` (note that my method to work properly needs no less than 1 character which is alpha in each `str`) and then slice it accordingly. I also use list comprehension to get `output`. `''.join` is required to get `str` from list of characters.

Answer (score 0):

Use this.

print([i[5:] for i in categories])